# What does this 'where' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

> “It is an art **where** you’ve got to deal with the demands
>   of every day but at the same time place it strategically
>   at the heart of what the company is doing.”
>   — Jeroen
>   Tas, group CIO of Philips 5

I have problem in where meaning. I think it mean "what".

EDIT: [Does the sentence mean "deal with demands of every day and also place it at the heart of what the company is doing in"?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27732649#27732649)

Comment: It's informal for "in which" , more or less.

Comment: what about this sentence " place it strategically"?

Comment: is this another question?

Comment: yes about this text

Comment: Have you looked up "strategic" in the dictionary?

Comment: I know what strategic mean. but here is ambiguous for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36038/discussion-between-gandalf-and-coder-android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ***where*** means "in which".

According to [*Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/where) (via The Free Dictionary), under the definition of *where*:

> Usage: It was formerly considered incorrect to use *where* as a substitute for *in which* after a noun which did not refer to a place or position, but this use has now become acceptable: *we now have a situation where/in which no further action is needed*

---

As for the meaning of the sentence, you got its main idea correctly. (Reading the chat log, I can see that you weren't sure about the structure of the sentence.) You asked, *does the sentence mean "deal with demands of every day and also place it at the heart of what the company is doing in"?* My answer is yes, more or less.

Here is how you can understand (and parse) the sentence:

> *It is an art where you’ve got to deal with the demands of every day but at the same time place it strategically at the heart of what the company is doing.*
>
> = It is an art. In this art, you've got to [ deal with the demands of every day ] but at the same time [ (you've got to) [ place it strategically at the heart of what the company is doing ] ].